# Jmeter method "patch"

Tags: jmeter, http-verbs

I'm load testing an API, where one of the verbs we used is [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789). in JMeter, when I create my HTTP request, I don't have patch as a method listed. can anyone tell me if PATCH is supported by JMeter?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello marcos, is the answer provided below the right one ? Thanks

Comment: It is now available see updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No patch is not supported as of JMeter 2.7.

see:

- https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53675

It has been implemented this night(08/23/2012) so it is now available in nightly build:

- https://builds.apache.org/job/JMeter-trunk/build?token=OnDemand

Feel free to test it and give feedback on jmeter user list or bugzilla.
Edit (10/6/2012):
It is officialy available in Jmeter 2.8 release which is out :

- http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html

Regards

Philippe M.

http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com

Comment: Great stuff. I'll go and have a look!